# Need help launching android youtube intent reciever from Webview

Tags: android, android-intent, webview

I have a app that loads a page in webview this page has random youtube links. I would like the youtube app to open when the user selects one of these links. I have tried to create an intent with no luck and I have searched the internet for days with no luck. Also the links will not necessarily be the same each time the page loads so they will need to be parsed. Can someone help me please? My code is below

```
import android.app.Activity;

        import android.content.Intent;

        import android.net.Uri;

        import android.os.Bundle;

        import android.view.View;

        import android.widget.Button;

        import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;

        import android.webkit.WebView;

        import android.webkit.WebViewClient;  



         public class Activity1 extends Activity {

            private WebView webView;



     @Override

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);  

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());  

        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.beatdrop.us/blog");  

        

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()

        {

         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)

         {

          // YouTube video link

          if (url.startsWith("vnd.youtube:"))

          {

           int n = url.indexOf("?");

           if (n > 0)

           {

        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,                                          
        Uri.parse(String.format("http://www.youtube.com/v/%s",
         url.substring("vnd.youtube:".length(),n)))));

           }

           return (true);

          }



          return (false);

         }

        });

        



        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity2.class);

                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

            }



             });

            }

    }
            <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="http"  android:host="youtube.com" android:pathPrefix="/watch" />
      <data android:scheme="https" android:host="youtube.com" android:pathPrefix="/watch" />
    </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="http"  android:host="*.youtube.com" android:pathPrefix="/watch" />
  <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*.youtube.com" android:pathPrefix="/watch" />
     </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="http"  android:host="www.youtube.com" android:pathPrefix="/v/" />
      <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.youtube.com" android:pathPrefix="/v/" />
      <data android:scheme="http"  android:host="www.youtube.com" android:pathPrefix="/e/" />
      <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.youtube.com" android:pathPrefix="/e/" />
      <data android:scheme="http"  android:host="www.youtube.com"      android:pathPrefix="/embed/" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.youtube.com" android:pathPrefix="/embed/" />
    </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="vnd.youtube" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Did you try to attach links to intent as is? Doesn't Youtube app appear in Application chooser dialog?

Comment: Egor what do you mean by attach links to the intent as is?

Comment: Well the links will change every time the page loads so I wont know what the links are ahead of time. Can you give me a sample of what your talking about or how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {
            String javascript = "javascript:" +
                "var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');" +
                "for (var i = 0, l = iframes.length; i < l; i++) {" +
                "   var iframe = iframes[i]," +
                "   a = document.createElement('a');" +
                "   a.setAttribute('href', iframe.src);" +
                "   d = document.createElement('div');" +
                "   d.style.width = iframe.offsetWidth + 'px';" +
                "   d.style.height = iframe.offsetHeight + 'px';" +
                "   d.style.top = iframe.offsetTop + 'px';" +
                "   d.style.left = iframe.offsetLeft + 'px';" +
                "   d.style.position = 'absolute';" +
                "   d.style.opacity = '0';" +
                "   d.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=0)';" +
                "   d.style.background = 'black';" +
                "   a.appendChild(d);" +
                "   iframe.offsetParent.appendChild(a);" +
                "}";
            view.loadUrl(javascript);

            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });
```